# How to comment on embedded facebook post on a website without leaving it

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I recently made a fanpage and i have used embedded code from one of the post of my fanpage to  my website.

So now It shows the post on my website and number of likes but i would like to show current existing comments which that particular post had got. Right now it is just displays the comment button and if i will click that then it will take me to the fanpage just for the sake of comment.

So heres what i need

1 - Comment on the embedded post without leaving the website to facebook.

2 - Displaying all the current existed comments ..

the image right now look like this

[image]

Comment: The plugin does not offer that option. If you want it, you will have to implement it yourself via API (and that would be a broader endeavor, and being able to comment that way would require your users to log into your app and give publishing permission first as well).

Answer (score 0):

Thats very simple. First, you need to login user and ask for publish_stream permission. After the user is logged in, you just to display a button that triggers the function named comment, passing the ID (corresponding to the object user is going to comment to) .

You will also need an input field for inserting the comment (of course), and using jquery .value we will get the value of the input field .

PS: Specify NAME and ID on the message input field. I dont remember wich one is, put both of them .

After getting the variables, we will call FB.api, specifing the variables id and comentario than get the response for handling  the result (if you want), you can try to reload the comment plugin, or refreshing the page .

```
function comment(id) {
                    var id = id;
                    var comentario = document.getElementById("message").value;
                    FB.api("/"+id+"/comments","POST",
                    {
                    "message": comentario
                    },
                    function (response) {
                                          if (response && !response.error) {
                                         alert('Comentado !');
                                        } else {
                                         alert('Erro !');
                                               }
                                    });
                    $("#atividade").html('COMENTADO');
        }
```

That is very simple and fun, but you will need to get authorization from facebook platform to ask users for publish_stream permissions before production .

Answer (score 0):

I think David's answer will just post a new comment, not show all post's comments.

Unfortunately there is not a option to show the comments on embed posts.
You need to get the post id, call a api to load all comments and so embed each one of them. Yeah, that's terrible...

Open the graph api explorer:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Type *{post-id}/comments* on GET input and send it to see a response example.

And that's how you embed comments:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-comments

I don't think loading all comments from all posts will have a good performance. I suggest you to create a button "see comments" which call the api. After that you can create the input text for new comments, like David said.